# Add a div after short description ending after meta in Woocommerce single product

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I need to do some styling to the Woocommerce single product page: I need a border around the price(which I moved above the add to cart button), in stock status, add to cart button and meta data. So basically a visual border around these items:
https://postimg.cc/image/jp6e1hpa9/

Since they are not in one specific div, I need to place a new div around them. How can I add this div around the above mentioned items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

If you have moved the product price above add to cart button with some code, the following code below **will replace your code as it also move the price** under product short description.

It also adds a div container html tag starting before the moved price and ending after the product meta data (see the screenshot at the end).

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_price', 3 );
function custom_single_product_price() {

    // Remove product price
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

    // Add back the product price after short description
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );

    // Opening div container (just after the product short description and before the moved product price)
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'opening_div_single_product_summary', 21 );

    // Closing div container (after the product meta data)
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'closing_div_template_single_price', 60 );
}

function opening_div_single_product_summary() {
    // Display the opening div
    echo '<div class="custom-container">';
}

function closing_div_template_single_price() {
    // Then display the closing div
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

Comment: :Sorry for not being thst clear. My structure for the product summary is the following: 1. Short description, 2. Price, 3. stock status, 4. add to cart button, 5. meta data(tags, sku etc). And I need the div around 2.- 5. , so NOT including the short description, but everything else.

Comment: @mark I have updated my code. My code will replace your customization and will add a div starting just after the product short description and ending after the product meta data… StackOverFlow questions and answers are read by a lot of people, so things need to be clear in your question (editing it please).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override woocommerce template structure from your respective theme. 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
After that please find price.php inside single-product folder (might be change on the latest version). We will find the HTML structure of the price there.

Comment: I don't want to edit the template as this is not he best way. I think there must be a way with a function, but I don't know how.